# Why is NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL is undefined on prod env NextJS+ useSWR

Tags: next.js, vercel

I want to deploy a small project on vercel. I am using `useSWR` to fetch data.

```
  const { data, error } = useSWR(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL + '/api/series', fetcher, {
    suspense: true,
  });
```

The value for `VERCEL_URL` on local is:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL="http://localhost:3000"
```

It works as expected on local with `npm run dev`.

Deployed to vercel and works fine on development branch.
with value as.
[image: dev]

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL=https://myapp-development-myname.vercel.app
```

I get the response and in network tab it works.

[image: response]

**Production environment**

I have changed the VERCEL_URL to my apps website name.

[image: prod]

There is a client side error as shown here.

[image: error]

The value is:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL=https://abc.myappproduction.com
```

Also the network tab shows the url is undefined.

[image: undefined]

Why does it get undefined value? Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that if the `useSWR` hook is making a request to an internal API route you don't even need the full URL. Using `useSWR('/api/series', fetcher, { suspense: true })` should work.

Comment: I have tried that! It works with `/api/series`. The problem is when you refresh the page. There is a error Only absolute URLS are supported.